# Returning grouped groups in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table 'tbl_words' that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | word    |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | Bob   | rabbit  |
|  2 | Bob   | hare    |
|  3 | Bob   | hare    |
|  4 | Bob   | chicken |
|  5 | Paul  | goose   |
|  6 | Paul  | chicken |
|  7 | Paul  | rabbit  |
|  8 | Paul  | hare    |
|  9 | Paul  | hare    |
| 10 | Paul  | chicken |
| 11 | Paul  | goose   |
| 12 | Laura | goose   |
| 13 | Laura | rabbit  |
| 14 | Laura | rabbit  |
| 15 | Laura | goose   |
| 16 | Laura | fox     |
+----+-------+---------+
```

I want to get the two most frequent occurrences of column 'word' for each column 'name'. The closest I can get with a query is this:

```
SELECT name, word, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
FROM tbl_words 
GROUP BY name, word 
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Which returns:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| name  | word    | magnitude |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Paul  | chicken |         2 |
| Laura | rabbit  |         2 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

However I'm looking for this:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| name  | word    | magnitude |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| Bob   | hare    |         2 |
| Bob   | chicken |         1 |
| Paul  | chicken |         2 |
| Paul  | goose   |         2 |
| Laura | rabbit  |         2 |
| Laura | goose   |         2 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

How can I achieve this i.e. get the two most common words per name?

Comment: That gives me the number of occurrences of each word per name, which is great. However it returns x number of rows per user where x is the number of unique values of word. I want to limit the number of rows per user to two, these two rows representing the words with the highest frequency per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want the greatest n per group so just count it up and filter with having like so

```
SELECT name, word, magnitude 
FROM(
    SELECT name, word, magnitude, IF(@a = name, @b := @b + 1, @b := 1) counting, @a := name
    FROM(
        SELECT name, word, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
        FROM tbl_words 
        GROUP BY name, word
        ORDER BY name, magnitude DESC
    ) t
    CROSS JOIN(select @a := '', @b := 0)temp
)t1
WHERE counting <=3
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abfe2a/26)

Comment: Thanks John. The fiddle you provided works well, but with an augmented data set the results are no longer limited to 2 words per name. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abfe2a/1 where Bob now turns up three times.

Comment: @TerryStephens oops sorry forgot to include an order on the name see my updated answer and sqlfiddle

Comment: That's spot on, but I have no idea how it works! How do I change the number of words per name? It looks like it should be as simple as changing HAVING counting <=2 to <=3 but this doesn't work.

Comment: @TerryStephens can you show me where its not working? <= 3 should be working

Comment: @TerryStephens actually i was able to replicate it.. not exactly sure why it was doing that but I just changed it.. see the edit.. that will give you any number per group

Comment: fthiella's solution works, but yours is neater and returns the information in exactly the format I asked for above so I've changed your answer to be the correct one. If you don't mind running me through the logic, I'd be interested to understand it more. Thanks!

Comment: ok so there are a few parts to this... first thing is get your magnitude order by the field you want to use to limit the results by (aka name) with the highest magnitude first... then on the next level is where the magic happens.. I use user defined variables in MySQL to do a row by row comparrison.. meaning I assign the variable to the name after checking the contents of that variable.. which would be the contents of the previous row... from there its a simple increment from that logic and then finally you just limit it by that increment by the number of times you want a repeat

Comment: the if statement says if (previousname = currentname then increment, else reset

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested , but your query should look like:

```
    SELECT name, word, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
    FROM tbl_words where name in 
(select name from   tbl_words ORDER BY magnitude DESC LIMIT 2)
    GROUP BY name, word
```

Comment: Thanks, but "doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'". I'm running version 5.5.25.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the number of occurences of each word for each user:

```
SELECT name, word, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM tbl_words
GROUP BY name, word
```

then we can use GROUP_CONCAT on this subquery, ordered by cnt desc:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(word ORDER BY cnt DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT name, word, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM tbl_words
  GROUP BY name, word
) s
GROUP BY name
```

that will return a comma separated list of all words, ordered by cnt in descending order.

Then you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the first two words:

```
SELECT name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(word ORDER BY cnt DESC), ',', 2) most_frequent
FROM (
  SELECT name, word, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM tbl_words
  GROUP BY name, word
) s
GROUP BY name
```

keep in mind that if more than two words have the same frequency, two random words will be selected.

Comment: Random selection of same frequency words is not a problem. This is great - thanks!